# Unable to delete Neo4j nodes based on condition

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I added a bunch of nodes to the database. All the nodes have a format that looks like this:

```
{"id":"10","guid":"...", "type":"object_1_"}
{"id":"11","guid":"...", "type":"object_1_"}
...
{"id":"11","guid":"...", "type":"object_N_"}
```

And this `^^^` is exactly what I get when I run a `START n=node(*) RETURN n` query.

However, when I try to delete some nodes based on a condition, then it does not work. So, this

```
MATCH (n{type:"object_1_"}) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() DELETE n,r
```

does not work. And I wonder why. Only a trivial case works:

```
MATCH (n) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() DELETE n, r
```

but this is not what I want. I want to have some condition, like the above one where `type` attribute is `object_1_`. So, how can I do that?

Comment: What does `MATCH (n{type:"object_1_"}) RETURN n` give you?

Comment: I found what was wrong. I issued this command through `curl` in command line like `"{\"query\":\"MATCH (n{type:\"object_1_\"}) ...} `and even though both `curl` and `neo4j` parser did not throw any error message, in fact the query was incorrect. So, I had to do `"\MATCH (n{type:'object_1_'})`. So, starters, please, pay attention to how you escape quotes.

Comment: And how are you running your queries? That's not what the results look like in neo4j shell or browser. Are you using the rest API?

Comment: Ok, you can put that in a n answer then, for the next guy. Also, if you surround the json string with single quotes you can use double quotes within without having to escape so much.

Comment: @ jjaderberg. Thanks for trying to help! I wish neo4j parser was more clever

Comment: "Also, if you surround the json string with single". The catch is I wanted to mimic `C++` strings, since in the final implementation I run this code in `C++`.

Comment: Have you tried to do it with `Match (n) where n.type="object_1_"` ?

Comment: @No, I've not tried that yet. But thanks for pointing to this kind of query. I'me new to neo4j and therefore it will be useful for me.

Answer (score 1):

The whole trouble was in the way how I ran this query in curl. The incorrect way was:

```
curl http://... -H ... -d "{\"query\":\"MATCH (n{type:\"object_1_\"}) 
                           OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() DELETE n,r\"}"
```

`Neo4j` parser did not throw any error message, but it was still incorrect. The right way to do was:

```
curl http://... -H ... -d "{\"query\":\"MATCH (n{type:'object_1_'})
                          OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() DELETE n,r\"}"
```

Comment: This is actually interesting. The problem is not the cypher parser however. Add the `-v` flag to curl to see a `HTTP 500` error. Then look at the stacktrace in `data/log/console.log`. It's the webserver's json parser (Jetty, Jackson) that's choking.